# R ‘shiny’ script, cannot find shiny package

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to open an R-shiny script that ran perfectly some months ago (I think there was an R and Rstudio update in between).

The program aborts when importing the library, which I am sure worked fine around that time.

My code:

```
#install.packages("shiny")
library(shiny)
runExample("01_hello")
```

The error message is:

> Error in library(shiny) : there is no package called ‘shiny’

Why is this not running anymore. What do I need to do to get this running?

Comment: If there was an upgrade in R, you may not have `shiny` installed for that version. Try installing it once again.

Comment: Try reinstalling `shiny` with `rm.packages("shiny"); install.packages("shiny")`

Comment: Use `.libPaths()` to see in which directories R looks for installed packages and make sure the current R version is in the list.